# wstool init fails

Tags: ros, catkin, wstool

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build catkin workspace following instructions.

```
mkdir -p  ~/overlay_ws
cd ~/overlay_ws
mkdir -p src
cd src
wstool init
```

But it is failing with:

```
ubuntu:~/overlay_ws/src$ wstool init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/wstool", line 63, in <module>
    sys.exit(wstool.wstool_cli.wstool_main(sys.argv))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/wstool/wstool_cli.py", line 217, in wstool_main
    'info': cli.cmd_info,
AttributeError: WstoolCLI instance has no attribute 'cmd_info'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57693/wstool-init-fails/) by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 147 on 2013-03-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-03-11**:
You should open an issue on the wstool issue tracker so that a better error message is displayed when this error occurs: https://github.com/vcstools/wstool/issues

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-03-11**:
I opened one: https://github.com/vcstools/wstool/issues/10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like your version of wstool is the most recent, but rosinstall is not up-to-date. This can happen on Ubuntu in particular if you have an old version of rosinstall in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages. Remove anything named rosinstall* or vcstool* in there.

The syntax should be okay, though the added dot as kalectro suggest is also okay, so that might be a workaround. Still you should update.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your formatting is really bad. You will have more people reading your question if you format your question a little nicer.

As far as I can see you are missing a dot. The command should be

`wstool init .`

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-03-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1